# Does using Split() always need to be paired with an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split, ecmascript-5

I've been looking at someone else's code and I'm stuck on some syntax that I can't make complete sense of.

http://jsfiddle.net/62NPt/53/

```
var $windows = $('#tgx-window,#tgs-window,#tgm-window,#tgl-window'), 
    $buttons = $('#tgx-button,#tgs-button,#tgm-button,#tgl-button');
    $windows.hide();

$buttons.on('click', function() {
    var $id;
    $buttons.removeClass('closebutton');
    $id = $('#' + this.id.split('-')[0] + '-window');// Get window id
    // alert($id);
    $windows.slideUp();
    if(! $id.is(':visible') ) {
        $id.slideDown();
        $(this).addClass('closebutton');
    }
});
```

The line I'm looking at is `$id = $('#' + this.id.split('-')[0] + '-window');`

I'm trying to make sense out of the index array value: [0] and why it's there at all.

According to the ECMAScript 5 specification, using the split() method "Returns an Array object". So the substring in question is being held at the index value [0] (even though there aren't any more values in the array (I assume).

Then we append "-window" and get our final value: $id = #tgx-window (if you clicked the #tgx-button value).

Is this correct? It's really clever imo. But I don't understand *why* split and an array value are being used together.

Also, I was trying to use alert(); calls directly after the $id statement to try and "look into what was being created" but I didn't find any useful information. Mostly [object Object] and [object HtmlDivElement] which didn't give me any ah-ha moments. What would you have done to glean some clarity from what was happening in the line: `$id = $('#' + this.id.split('-')[0] + '-window');// Get window id` ??

If you read this far, thank you so much. I haven't had this much fun looking at code in years. It's an awesome feeling :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your problem is. `.split` *always* returns an array. So you have to access the element of the array that you want to get (`0` in this case).

Comment: Exactly like above. In you particular case you are accessing first element of the array ([0]) which stands before the "-" sign.

Comment: Yeah, I think that was my confusion. Split *always* creates an array. Thanks

Comment: If I wanted to "see" the value of $id right after it was created (notice my alert() right after the $id statement) how would I have done that? Eg. alert(print value of $id) // prints "#tgx-window"

Comment: `alert($id.attr('id'));` try this.

Comment: Or `console.log($id)`.

Comment: Oh I like console.log. Thank you for showing me!

Answer (score 1):

You have the following IDs

```
$windows = $('#tgx-window,#tgs-window,#tgm-window,#tgl-window'), 
$buttons = $('#tgx-button,#tgs-button,#tgm-button,#tgl-button');
```

Since "this" will only reffer to the button. Split splits the ID to an array eg. (tgx,button);

hence

```
$('#' + this.id.split('-')[0] + '-window');
```

this.id.split('-')[0] will equal tgx (if #tgx-button is clicked);

This is the same as

```
$('#tgx-window');
```

**EDIT**

```
alert('#' + this.id.split('-')[0] + '-window')
```

will alert the ID

Comment: Thanks. It finally clicked! It seems really clever for what he/she was trying to accomplish too. Or I'm just easily impressed at this stage :)

Answer (score 1):

Split method always returns an array. You are accessing the element at the first index of the returned array. 
You can know more about Split [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)